# how to keep the changed image when child is open in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

MY CODE---

[HTML CODE]

```
 <div class="hidden_menu_opener" title="More...."></div>
 <div class="hidden_menu_container" style="display:none;">
     <div class="hidden_menu_arrow"></div>
     <div class="hidden_menu"></div>
 </div>
```

[JAVASCRIPT CODE]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $hidden_menu_opener = $(".hidden_menu_opener");
    var $hidden_menu = $(".hidden_menu_container");
    $hidden_menu_opener.click(function () {
        $hidden_menu.toggle();
    });
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var hidden_menu = $(".hidden_menu_container");
    if (!hidden_menu.is(e.target)&& hidden_menu.has(e.target).length === 0){
        hidden_menu.hide(1);
    }
});
```

---

Explanation----

i have a trigger with a class "hidden_menu_opener" which when clicked displays the hidden div with class "hidden_menu_container"

WHAT DO I WANT TO DO-----

the div "hidden_menu_opener" has a background image whose opacity is 0.63 on the page load but changes to full opacity(1) when hovered.now i want the image to stay on full opacity as long as the "hidden_menu_container" is visible

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to update your css and js for staying on full opacity:

CSS:

```
.hidden_menu_opener {
     opacity: 0.63;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 10px;
}
.hidden_menu_opener:hover, .hidden_menu_opener.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $hidden_menu_opener = $(".hidden_menu_opener");
    var $hidden_menu = $(".hidden_menu_container");
    $hidden_menu_opener.click(function () {
        $hidden_menu.toggle();
        $hidden_menu_opener.toggleClass('active');
    });
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    var hidden_menu = $(".hidden_menu_container");
    if (!hidden_menu.is(e.target)&& hidden_menu.has(e.target).length === 0){
        hidden_menu.hide(1);
        $hidden_menu_opener.toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

Could you please review the example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MHDTK/)?